# performance of list.remove(value) in Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Suppose a list contains a list of integers, if I call `list.remove(100)` to remove element with value 100, wondering if it is `O(n)` or `O(logN)`? I thought it is `O(n)`, but not sure if Python 2.7 list has any internal optimizations to improve performance even further. Thanks.

regards,
Lin

Comment: You can alway verify yourself. Create lists of different sizes, carry out a null action to get the time the overhead takes, and then carry out the action, and calculate how long it takes in relation to the list length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Removing an item from a list in Python is O(n)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). This is because the underlying space in memory must be "shifted over" now that an element is missing. There are other implementations of lists, such as a linked list, that you could use in Python for constant time removal, but the built in List data structure is definitively O(n)

Comment: Thanks James, the performance list of reference is awesome. Vote up. Mark your reply as answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Mark your reply as answer, thanks James for the help. :)